# SailsJS stop unwanted data entering the database

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, sails.js

So, with sailsJS you can just put any old data into your model and put it into the database even if the  item is not defined in the `attributes` object.

Is there any way to prevent this happening? is seems silly to try and do an `if` and then throw errors because there would be too many things to stop getting through.

For example I have just ran into the problem where I have a list of users and I'm displaying them through angular `ng-repeat` on the frontend and when I `put` the data to save a user it also decides that  `"$$hashKey": "00I"` is going with them too **!**

So it automatically saved to the database and when I refresh and get the data again, the `"$$hashKey": "00I"` is coming back, and therefore causing this error

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by'
>       expression to specify unique keys. 
>       Repeater: (key, user) in admins | filter:userSearch, Duplicate key: object:00I

This is coming from angular.

ps.

> as far as i know, the server is using the default sails-disk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default mode for Sails.js models is schemaless, which is probably not what you need. So, all you have to do is to add schema to your model:

```
module.exports = {
 schema: true,

 attributes: {
   // Define all your attributes here...
 }
};
```

After that all the values that are not described in the `attributes` will be automatically filtered out during the model saving.